# OpenCv : How to read h.265 video file with dynamic fps and know time passed by?

Tags: python, opencv, h.264, frame-rate, h.265

### Problem

I have recorded 15minutes h.265 video file. With python & opencv, using video capture I  can easily open, preview and analyze file content. But there is one problem - `changing FPS`!

File normally has 25 FPS when movement is detected. But when there is no movement on screen, file is recorded with 1FPS (each frame is one second). I would like to analyze video file in parts equal to 5 minutes? How to know when 5 minutes passed by, when FPS is changing and each frame could have diffrent length?

### Update

As mentioned in comments, i've used ffprobe to analyze content of my video. Here is json output of ffprobe :

```json
{
    "packets": [
        {
            "codec_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "duration": 48000,
            "duration_time": "0.040000",
            "size": "125201",
            "pos": "0",
            "flags": "K_"
        },
        {
            "codec_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "duration": 48000,
            "duration_time": "0.040000",
            "size": "4811",
            "pos": "125201",
            "flags": "__"
        },
        {
            "codec_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "duration": 48000,
            "duration_time": "0.040000",
            "size": "4712",
            "pos": "130012",
            "flags": "__"
        },
        {
            "codec_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "duration": 48000,
            "duration_time": "0.040000",
            "size": "4719",
            "pos": "134724",
            "flags": "__"
        },
        {
            "codec_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "duration": 48000,
            "duration_time": "0.040000",
            "size": "5365",
            "pos": "139443",
            "flags": "__"
        },
         ... part cutted because it was too big ...
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "hevc",
            "codec_long_name": "H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/25",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 2560,
            "height": 1920,
            "coded_width": 2560,
            "coded_height": 1920,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "pix_fmt": "yuvj420p",
            "level": 153,
            "color_range": "pc",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/1200000",
            "nb_read_packets": "3727",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can **try** CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC. it *may* or may *not* give sensible values.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. This is a specific .265 format from China manufacturer. Maybe it could be readed also with information about length of each frame?

Comment: use ffprobe, show_streams and show_packets. I'd recommend `-of json`. look at the information, specifically presentation timestamps (PTS). https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html OpenCV is the wrong tool. It's for computer vision, not for reading video files. you need to use ffmpeg's *APIs* directly. PyAV is the only proper python wrapper for ffmpeg that I've seen. all the others are *toys* that use a subprocess and move data through pipes.